# Exported MailChimp HTML template is looking different

Tags: html, css, html-email, mailchimp

When I send test mail from MAilchimp it looks fine

[image: Email sent from mailchimp]

But when I export the template code and send it through putsmail.com or other service it strips the styling 
[image: Email sent through putsmail]

What am I missing here ?

[The Code i.e. html n css](http://www.pasteall.org/52445)

Comment: without the html and css, no-one can help you

Comment: @martincarlin87 where do I share it ? Stackoverflow has character limitation

Comment: css styles need to write inline

Comment: it's usually best to include it in the question in order to not rely on external links but mkaing a fiddle is good to allow people to tinker with it - http://jsfiddle.net/sKLy4/. Seems fine there too.

Comment: @martincarlin87 thanks forgot about jsfiddle

Answer (score 14):

When you export your email template from Mailchimp the css is still in the head of the email and is not inlined yet. Gmail strips out the CSS automatically which is why it looks different. All email clients handle this differently which is why it's good to inline your styles. Mailchimp actually offers their own inliner tool.

Run the exported HTML through this and then try sending the new inlined code. It should get you closer to where you want to be.

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

This answer might be late but hopefully it helps.